# ASP: Send a Request String from a Button onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I'm using aspx and aspx.cs file.

I need to have buttons onclick event which send data to the cs file to do something with the database.

So far my only problem is how to send the data which is selected.

My aspx page is

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="London" value="London" onclick="Page_Load" />  
   <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="Paris" value="Paris" onclick="Page_Load" />  
   <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="Madrid" value="Madrid" onclick="Page_Load" />  
</form>
```

and the aspx.cs page is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  

        String city= Request.QueryString["city"];
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("xx");
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where City = city", sqlCon);
....
    }
```

so the problem is that i don't know how to send the chosen value. How can i do it? Thanks

Comment: go to tutorial site first and learn

Comment: this can do even with mouse clicks, how you have end up with this code ? Start from a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Click event and Page Load event, here u go :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="London" value="London" OnClick="Button_Click" />  
   <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="Paris" value="Paris" OnClick="Button_Click" />  
   <asp:Button ID="city" runat="server" Text="Madrid" value="Madrid" OnClick="Button_Click" />  
</form>


protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String city= Request.QueryString["city"];
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("xx");
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where City = city", sqlCon)
}
```